# Can't reproduce results in NLTK Book, Document Classification (Chapter 6, section 1.3)

Tags: python, nltk, document-classification

From here:  http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html (section 1.3).

The authors cite an accuracy of .81.

There is, of course, some randomness involved due to the random.shuffle, but no matter how many times I run this I can't get above .73.

(There is an additional weirdness in that the authors claim that word_features below contains the 2000 most frequent words, but this isn't true (compare to list(all_words.most_common(2000)).)

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)\
                 for category in movie_reviews.categories()\
                 for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in movie_reviews.words())
word_features = list(all_words)[:2000]

def document_features(document, words_to_use = word_features):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in words_to_use:
        features['contains({})'.format(word)] = (word in document_words)
    return features


featuresets = [(document_features(d), c) for (d,c) in documents]

train_set, test_set = featuresets[100:], featuresets[:100]

classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

print(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))
```

Comment: Do you get better accuracy if you use the 2000 most frequent words?

Comment: @lenz, No, worse accuracy, since most of the 2000 most frequent words ("the", "a", "he"...) carry very little information about category.

Answer (score 0):

1. `list(all_words)[:2000]` is definitely not the top 2000 most common words comparing to actual `[word for word, _ in all_words.most_common(2000)]`
2. > No, worse accuracy, since most of the 2000 most frequent words ("the", "a", "he"...) carry very little information about category

Sure, these *stopwords* are not so useful (they are less informative features), but take into account the fact that there are couple of them (~30) and the rest (~1900) are still good relevant features.

What I would suggest to do in such a situation:

1. Do not use `random.shuffle(document)` to guarantee the order of them
2. Use actual 2000 **most common** words as your features (as in example provided above)
3. Post your results including Python version and NLTK version. You can check both with

`python --version`

`python -c "import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)"`